# How to get a variable from multi-variable instance of a class?

Tags: c#, class

i have a simple class like this:

```
public class r_event
{
    string name;
    double time;

    public r_event()
    {
        name = "none";
        time = 0;
    }

    public r_event(string name, double time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

and i have made an instance in another class as below:

```
    r_event event1 = new r_event("SH_S", 2);
```

but i want to assign just one of these two variable (event,time) to a local variable of my second class;

in fact i want to declare (for example) an string named "name" in second class and assign just "name" property of r_event class instance to name.
a thing like this:

```
     string name = event1.name;
```

but it is not possible. How can i do this job?

Comment: Set add getter methods.

Comment: Please take a look at [C# Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the fields you already have public by simply adding the keyword ***public***. For example

```
public string name;
public double time;
```

This will allow you access them outside of the class.
In truth it's better to create (public) properties than to use public fields. You could implement this by adding the following...

```
public string Name
{
    get { return name: }
    set { name = value; }
}

public double Time
{
    get { return time; }
    set { time = value; }
}
```

Hope this helps (and might I suggest you look into properties and accessibility/ access modifiers).

Comment: i added "public" keyword but when i Construct an instance like:
 r_event e = new r_event(); 
then assign to a string like:
string name = e.Name;
system show this error: field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method....on assignment!?

Comment: Try implementing the properties instead of using your public fields.

Comment: I've just ran your code, and with the public access modifiers it works? I notice you said you did `string name = e.Name;` unless you have changed the name of the field from `name` to `Name` (notice the upper case 'n') then this will indeed give you an error.

Answer (score 1):

just ran your code please not that variables not specified in regards to their accessibility are `private by default` this works I just tested it if you declare the variables access as `public` please read [C# MSDN Access Modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx)

```
public class r_event
{
    public string name;
    public double time;

    public r_event()
    {
        name = "none";
        time = 0;
    }

    public r_event(string name, double time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

call it the same way

```
r_event event1 = new r_event("SH_S", 2);
```

If you are familiar with `Auto-Property's` you could do the same this way

```
public class r_event
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double time { get; set; }

    public r_event()
    {
        name = "none";
        time = 0;
    }

    public r_event(string name, double time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `public string name;`, your variable is not accessible by its protection level.